# Having a PHP variable in an href=

Tags: php

I'm looking to do something like this, although I know this doesn't work.

```
<?php
$page = "page.php"
?>
<a href=$page>Click</a>
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? thanks

Comment: yes, use the php tags, as you already did when you assigned the variable

Comment: You must read the documentation on how PHP works before asking a question like this, Sam. Also, you're going to have a syntax error if you don't put a semicolon `;` at the end of each line of PHP code.

Answer (score 9):

```
<a href="<?php echo $page; ?>">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `<a href='<?php echo $page; ?>'>` instead. That'll echo the value of `$page` into the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

if short open tags are enabled.

```
<a href="<?= $page ?>">Click</a>
```

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev that one was removed.. but it used short echo on the return value of the echo function (that's always void) :)

Comment: @mishu Have you ever encountered a scenario where they are disabled? PHP >= 5.4 will always allow printing through short tags, regardless of the directive.

Comment: @Matt i am knew about that, but before update code was <a href="<?= echo $page ?>">Click</a>

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev Ah. OK, I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @MetalFrog no, that's not true.. from 5.4 the short echo won't depend on the short open tags directive and yes, I met cases when it was disabled because it is recommended to keep it this way.. because it creates conflicts with xml see this http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: @mishu the conflicts only happen with ASP-style tags `<? ?>` not shorthand echo tags `<?= ?>`.

Comment: @Matt yes, that's what we were talking about, the short open tags and the fact that up until 5.4 the short echo depends on that directive

Comment: @mishu OK, I was just clarifying. :-)

Comment: @Matt :) OK.. it seems that this poor question caused some discussions (and some reputation for pointing to use the php tags if I might add)

Answer (score 1):

Well you ended php script before using $page...
So you could just do this

```
<?php
$page = "page.php"    
echo("<a href=".$page.">Click</a>");
?>
```

Edit: to everone reminding me I should not echo html code directly.
That was clear to me ;-), in this HUGE example i felt like not closing the php tags and reopen them.
I wonder why no one mentioned the missing body/head and doc-type.

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev just because it's bad practice doesn't mean it's incorrect. To expand your argument, the assignment shouldn't even be in the same file as the HTML since you're now combining data and views.

Comment: There's a couple things about this that bug me. You don't need parenthesis when using things like `print` or `echo` because they are language constructs. You're using double quotes which will parse variables, but you escape the string for the variable, negating the use of the double quotes.